# NextJS Dev server not launching when using code-server on android

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, next.js, termux, code-server

I’m trying to work on a NextJS project with vscode via my android tablet. I installed [code-server](https://github.com/coder/code-server) in order to use vscode in the android device. Everything worked and installed perfectly, but when I try to launch the dev server using `npm run dev`, I get `Error: Unsupported platform: android`. Is there any way to work around this?
I'm using the [termux](https://termux.dev/en/) terminal for android.

The full error:

```
Error: Unsupported platform: android
at /root/ziv/repos/raanana-transport/node_modules/next/dist/lib/download-wasm-swc.js:84:31
at Object.downloadWasmSwc (/root/ziv/repos/raanana-transport/node_modules/next/dist/lib/download-wasm-swc.js:98:7)
at async /root/ziv/repos/raanana-transport/node_modules/next/dist/build/swc/index.js:114:13
```

Thank you.

Comment: it's not going to work on the platform.

Comment: @OMiShah isn't there any workaround this problem? It seems like it is a problem with the builder of Next.js or something, and maybe something can be changed in the config or additional script.